# External Blu Ray drive or internal + enclosure?

Tags: usb, drivers, hardware-rec, blu-ray

I bought an external Blu-ray drive for my MBP but it failed, and is going back. It felt really cheaply made so now I'm wondering whether to try and find a better one (all the reviews mention tacky build quality) or spend more and buy a nice internal one and put it in a USB 3.0 enclosure.

I fear if I post links to the models I'm considering the question will be closed as "subjective" so what I'm really after is any actual technical reasons why an internal drive in an enclosure would be a bad idea (drivers?). I'm not too fussed about the performance as it's only for ripping, not actually watching blurays.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: The actual drive you get if you say purchase a External ASUS Blu-Ray player is likely the exact same device as the internal ASUS Blue-Ray player.  besides disk enclosures for optical disk drives are very rare for a reason.

Comment: That's fair enough. The point really was that there's a lot more choice for internal drives, and all the external ones are in terrible plasticy boxes.

Comment: Your question is not clear.  The actual device is the likely the same between the form factors.  Beyond that I don't understand the question

Comment: That *was* my question. One is a black box, the other is a SATA drive in an enclosure that "converts" as it were, SATA to USB. I was wondering if there were going to be driver issues, incompatibility issues etc. If the black-box solution is basically the same (albeit in a smaller box) then that's my question answered.

Comment: The external drive will work out of the box.  The one you have to put in an enclosure yourself won't

Answer (score 1):

At a high level, there is no difference really between an internal BluRay drive in an external enclosure, and an external BluRay drive. The latter might be a bit more compact (because they can mass-produce form-fitted enclosures with slimline drives), but electronically they should be about the same.